# Perfino session timeout settings

Tags: perfino

I am getting "Session expired" in Perfino UI too often.
Is it possible to increase a timeout? I did not find related settings in /opt/perfino/perfino.properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to websockets, unfortunately there is currently no option to increase this timeout. The communication mechanism is being reworked so this message will not be displayed again starting with perfino 2.1.